# Custom APEX HTTP POST class fails to pass code coverage

Tags: apex, code-coverage, sandbox, apexrest

I wrote a simple APEX class that should send some data as a HTTP POST request to some webhook. It receives some parameters as a collection and is called from a flow.

```
global class send_sms_to_webhook {

    @InvocableMethod 
    public static void post_to_webhook(List<List<String>> input) {

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(''); //AWS endpoint
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ');
        request.setBody('{"number":"' + input.get(0).get(0) + '","body":"' + input.get(0).get(1) + '","title":"' + input.get(0).get(2) + '"}');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    }
}
```

For this post I left the Authorization and Endpoint out.
Everything works well in the sandbox, but when I push it to production it fails code coverage.

Comment: How does the Test Class looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Did you write test code for this class? You need to create a test class that calls the method in your class, and a separate class that implements the `HttpCalloutMock` interface, which your test class invokes. In this class you mock a response to your callout.

Relevant documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm